# Fragment makes App exits on back press instead of loading parent activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm dealing with a scenario where I have an activity named `HomeActivity` which contains `BottomAppBar` and inside that activity I'm loading fragments when user clicks on icons placed in bottom app bar. Now the issue that I'm facing is that when I load fragment from home activity it opens but on back press it exits the app instead of reloading home activity layout. Instead of that I want to load home activity whenever back is pressed inside any loaded fragment code snippet attached below:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.homePage:
                         fragment = new Fragment1();
                        break;

                    case R.id.wallet:
                        fragment = new Fragment2();
                        break;

                    case R.id.myorders:
                        fragment = new Fragment3();
                        break;

                    case R.id.search:
                         fragment = new Fragment4();
                        break;
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.rl_mainLayout, fragment).commit();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Moreover, i have an override method of `onBackPressed()` which contains call to method `finishAffinity()`

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finishAffinity();
    }
```

Comment: `finishAffinity();` closes the whole task stack afaik so it is not surprising that it closes the app.

Comment: yes i know that but if i remove this, it navigates it straight back to splash screen from fragment skipping the home screen

Comment: That sounds like a completely different issue and that's the one you should be fixing instead, and this is not the solution

Answer (score 0):

just don't call `finishAffinity()` always, it is breaking your navigation flow... you should just call `super` in there for proper behavior

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

and `finishAffinity()` is just closing all activities. the real question is why you have intentional `finishAffinity()` call in `onBackPressed` and why you wondering it is working (not switching fragments, just closing `HomeActivity` and others if on activitys stack in background)

if you really need `finishAffinity()` call you probably should make it only when first `Fragment` is visible

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isFirstFragmentVisible()) {
        finishAffinity();
        return; // prevent super call, handled
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

`isFirstFragmentVisible()` implement by own as homework, probably easiest way would be to check in this method which `Fragment` is currently loaded into `R.id.rl_mainLayout` (useful might be `findFragmentById()` or `findFragmentByTag()`)

Comment: let me try this and i'll get back to you if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

According to what I assume you are trying to do is.
you have 4 fragments in home activity. suppose user click on fragment 2, and then if he click back then fragment 1 should be displayed rather than splash or app exit. For this use the code below.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (currentFragment instanceOf Fragment1) {
       super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else
   {  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.rl_mainLayout, 
      fragment1).commit();
   }
    
}
```

set currentFragment value equal to fragment1 by default and then change its value on onNavigationItemSelected accordingly.